# How to change dir to the last directory?

Tags: shell, directory, cd-command

I have very long directories list, like

```
/dir/dir/dir/../../../../../../../../../..         ../../  ../../last dir
```

Is it possible to change to the last dir immediately?

Comment: What do you mean with `last dir`? The last one you visited, the last one in a list of subdirectories of the directory you are in. Your example is not very helpful

Comment: the last sub directory

Comment: Are you using "`..`" to represent parent directories or ellipses?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if `lastdir` is the only directory of that name in your directory hierarchy, you might get away with this in `bash` (although it may take a while to run)

```
shopt -s globstar
cd **/lastdir
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not think it would make much sense to implement such functionality in 'cd'.. It would work if every subdir had only one sub-subdir, but what if there's a tree [i.e. several subdirs in a dir]? Which path should it take? 'cd' is not a mind reader.

Consider the following two direcroty trees:

```
<some_parent_dir>
|
|-<subdir>
| |
| |-<subdir> 
|   |
|   |-<subdir>
|     |
|     |-<subdir>
|       |
|       |-<subdir>
|         |
|         |-<subdir>
|
|-<other_parent_dir>
```

in this (above) case 'cd' function you are asking for would work fine
However in the following case 'cd' would be confused not knowing which subdir it should enter: subdir1 or subdir2...

```
<some_parent_dir>
|
|-<subdir>
| |
| |-**<subdir1>** 
| | |
| | |-<subdir>
| |   |
| |   |-<subdir>
| |
| |-**<subdir2>**
|   |
|   |-<subdir>
|
|-<other_parent_dir>
```

In this case the best way out would be making sensible directory trees. Avoid creating chains of directories containing a single subdir.

However.. if you already have such a directories structure and you're in an interactive shell - use BASH and it's  autocomplete function... if a directory contains a single element 
    cd come_parent_dir ....
will eventually bring you to either the last directory in a dir-chain or to a directory having more than one dir (you'll be asked where you want to go further)

Comment: `cd` is a mind reader to some degree. Set `$CDPATH` and then `cd "any_child_dir_of_any_path_in_$CDPATH"`.

Comment: well this is cheating :) although it is a good point..

Answer (score -3):

`cd -` will change to the last directory you were in.

Comment: You misinterpreted what the OP meant. In this case, the OP did not mean “last” as in “the directory I was most recently in”; the OP meant “the directory referred to as ``last dir`` in the example”.